# Xcode: "No such module" embedded framework

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, frameworks

I currently have 3 Embedded Frameworks in my project:

- `PersistenceLayer` (Swift only)
- `TransportLayer` (Swift Only)
- `Socket` (Objc)

Both `PersistenceLayer` and `Socket` don't reference anything outside themselves.  However `TransportLayer` imports `PersistenceLayer` and `Socket`.  Oddly, I can *use* `PersistenceLayer` objects after importing:

```
import PersistenceLayer

struct User : Model {
  ...
}
```

`Model` is defined in `PersistenceLayer` and Xcode lets me use it per normal.  However, when I try to build `TransportLayer`, I get the error: `No such Modul 'Persistencelayer'`.  So Xcode recognizes the module is there, but somehow "looses" it when it builds.

What's maddening is that this used to work.  At some point something changed and I can't figure out what.  It's important to note that I work on a project with multiple developers and I have `merged` in changes.  However switching to a commit prior to the merge didn't work.  I've also tried:

- Adding `$(SRCROOT)` (recursive) to Framework Search Paths
- Deleting everything out of `ModuleCache` directory
- Clean project
- Clean Build Folder

I suspect that something changed in my project settings but I can't figure out what and I've checked the git diffs didn't help (there nothing that really changed in the project aside from the normal file additions.

Also, `TransportLayer` does successfully import and use `Socket`.  I can build the TransportLayer if I remove references to `PersistenceLayer` but keep all the references to `Socket`.

Does anyone know why this might be occurring or how to fix it?

### Update

Ok, so I removed the "offending" files from the target to make sure `Socket` was working (it is) and then re-added the files to the target (quite literally by resetting git).  It now builds... cause that makes sense.  But I tried changing the Scheme from `iOS Device` to a simulator and it no longer builds, but I'm getting different errors:

- in module.modulemap: `Header`PersistenceLayer-Swift.h' not found`
- Also: `Could not build Objective-C module 'Persistence Layer'`

This feels like I'm chasing down random errors...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the answer: Open up *Build Phases* in the `TransportLayer` target and manually add `PersistenceLayer` and `Socket` to *Target Dependencies*.  This ensures the that anything `TransportLayer` depends on will be built before it is.

I had a hunch that the original reason `iOS Device` scheme was working was because I had removed the offending files, allowing everything to build properly, including `PersistenceLayer` which was cached.  After adding the imports back into to the project it continued to work because `PersistenceLayer` didn't need to be built anymore. Other Schemes didn't work because `PersistenceLayer` wasn't built for those architectures.  I confirmed this by cleaning again and the builds failed.  After some searching around, I found `Target Dependencies` and added my two dependencies there.  Everything now builds properly in all schemes and all architectures.

My project probably had been working fine until now because it was working with cached Frameworks that had been built prior to me actually using them: (I built `PersistenceLayer` before I began work on `TransportLayer`). I probably cleaned the project sometime recently, which deleted the cached frameworks and caused the issues.